# Alternatives to cd/ls for command line navigation?

Tags: command-line, unix, terminal, ls

I generally work a fair amount from the command line in order to launch vim, git, ssh and so on. However, I find the Finder's columnar view more natural for browsing through my files. Unfortunately, it's less natural for everything I want to do with the files.

What about the best of both worlds? Are there any popular command line programs / commands out there that deviate from the standard set by the venerable `cd` and `ls` for navigating and browsing files in the terminal? I'm sure people must have tried interesting ways of visualizing files, opening folders, etc.

Comment: I once patched `bash`. When you pressed tab you could select the dir/file from an ncurses dialog. for some tasks it was really great for others quite annoying.

Answer (score 8):

[Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/) (`mc`) is one such tool that I'm aware of.

Comment: Interesting. I just installed it with homebrew and it certainly is an alternative to cd and ls. I'll keep playing around with it; not sure if it's any more useful or natural. Thanks for the excellent answer.

Comment: +1 for installing it with Homebrew. Mac users: Just type "brew install mc"

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to look at:

- readline setting `completion-ignore-case (Off)`

  > If set to On, readline performs filename matching and completion in a case-insensitive fashion.
- `shopt -s autocd`

  > If set, a command name that is the name of a directory is executed as if it were the argument to the cd command. This option is only used by interactive shells.
- `shopt -s globstar`

  > This example will recursively find all csproj files in the current directory and subdirectories:

  ```
  git commit -m update -- **/*.csproj`
  ```
- shell options `extglob`, and `nocaseglob`

  > for obvious purposes, see [`man bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)
- the `CDPATH` variable

  > `cd [-L|-P] [dir]`
  >
  > ```
  >   [...] The variable `CDPATH` defines the search path for the 
  >   directory containing dir. [...] If dir begins with a slash 
  >   (`/`), then `CDPATH` is not used
  > ```

Answer (score 1):

If you're a vim fan, you might also check out [vifm](http://vifm.sourceforge.net/), which "is a ncurses based file manager with vi like keybindings. If you use vi, vifm gives you complete keyboard control over your files without having to learn a new set of commands."

Answer (score 0):

I think this is similar to [this question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420456/open-terminal-here-in-mac-os-finder). If so, the most flexible option might be Big Cat and your own scripts. Sadly, the usual Big Cat URL is gone, so [here's the archive.org version](http://web.archive.org/web/20060704155140/http://ranchero.com/bigcat/). No idea if it works in your preferred version of OS X.

Answer (score 0):

CD Deluxe (Linux & Windows), it is very similar to the `cd` command, just with many more features, description from their website:

> Cd Deluxe is a drop-in replacement for the standard cd ("change directory") command. It supports easier access to the history of directories visited. It is kind of a "Swiss Army Knife" of changing directories. It is designed to increase productivity by speeding up the workflow of command line use. It is available for Windows and Unix style operating systems.

Download it at http://www.plan10.com/cdd/

Answer (score 0):

Don't go sleeping on pushd and popd;

Stores records of navigation on something called a directory stack for nice retrieval!

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-shell-scripting/9781785284441/ch03s11.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).